# In SR latch when apply a pulse to reset latch how the Q is changed?

Tags: flipflop, latch, reset

Here is the initial state of SR latch both reset and set inputs are zero.

[image]

Here we apply a pulse to the reset input and it shows it changes in this way
first -
[image]

and then -
[image]

The thing that I don't understand how R pulse can change Q state without receiving feedback signal from second NOR gate, and second NOR gate must receive feedback  signal from first NOR gate  which one of them happens first?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The truth table of a NOR gate tells you that the output will only be 1, if both inputs are 0. As soon as one input gets to logic 1, the output switches to a logic 0.

When *R* is set to 1, the condition of both inputs being zero is no longer fulfilled -> The output goes immediately low to 0.
At this time the lower NOR gate still has to wait for the logic 0 to appear at its upper input - until than it will stay low. But as soon as the higher input sees the 0 from *Q*, the gate has two low 0 as input and will switch the output to 1.

Comment: thank you   very much. Oh it's very simple .it's really frustrating   not to understand something because of very simple  thing. but it happens.

Comment: Happens to anyone!